# How many Jenkins Executors can you have?

Tags: jenkins, executor, parallel-builds

I'm running parallel tests with Jenkins.

The way I have it set up is I have a build flow job that executes three other jobs, in parallel. The three other jobs are connected to separate Test XML files.

When I initially started this I had a problem that only two jobs would execute at the same time and the third job would only execute after one of the others had finished.

I found this to be due to my Jenkins having the number of executors set to `2`, which is now set to `5`.

However, as a matter of interest, just for future planning, does Jenkins have a cap on the amount of executors you can have? Or is there a recommended number that you shouldn't exceed? Or would it be solely down to the environment you are running it on?

If there is a cap/recommend number not to exceed? I presume the best way to deal with this would be to use a master/slave scenario and spread the workload across multiple VMs.

For example, if I had it set to 6 executors, would this mean I would have 6 executors on each VM? Or 6 executors that are shared out between the VMs?

Answer (score 11):

It really depends on your environment and the amount of resources allocated to that instance of Jenkins. I do not believe there is any limit to the amount of executor that Jenkins allows. We currently run a single instance of Jenkins with 20 executors with no problems. Of course, depending on your build pipeline and commit patterns, you may find that the number of executors you set is too high. You would just have to keep an eye on whether you actually used all the executors at any given time.

If you find that you are nearing the ceiling of resource for your instance of Jenkins and you can't increase the resource limits then you would want to start using slaves.

One way we keep an eye on resource usage is through the [Monitoring plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring).

***Edit:

We recently had to reevaluate our executor to processor ratio due to what our pipelines are actually doing. You really need to determine how CPU bound your pipelines / jobs are. This will inevitable vary between use cases.

In our case, our pipelines were very CPU bound and became more so as we optimized our system, introduced parallel processing, etc. We ended up with one executor per cpu core, with a few extra "admin" executors to run quick / lightweight tasks.

We currently run jenkins on a single machine with 20 cores, but again, this will vary depending on your use case. We had to do a lot of calculations to determine how many excutors / cpu cores we need based off of our build frequency and target build time. When we eventually have to increase our processing power, we'll end up utilizing slaves to distribute jobs between multiple machines.

One other note: you also need to take into account the available memory since increasing the number of executors increases the amount of memory consumed. We had a case where we had enough processing power but not enough memory, which resulted in Jenkins' processes crashing due to OutOfMemory errors.

Comment: Hi @TheEllis. Thanks for your answer! I will have a look into that monitoring program, would be useful as to find out what I can achieve and not achieve.

Comment: It seems to be like usual- In `# of executors` label help- under question mark: `"..A good value to start with would be the number of CPU cores on the machine."`. But of course, depends on environment like RAM, tmp space amount, etc..
We have 8 cores, but only 5 executors at master node.

Comment: What yours server size?

Comment: Omer, I added an Edit to my post above

Answer (score 6):

I've been poking around this same question and found this next to the field in Jenkins itself:

*edit: to be more specific, Jenkins version 2.73.3, in the UI, in your job's configuration there should be little `?`s on the right side of each field. If you click them, they'll give you some more details about what's expected in that field. In the case of the executors field, you should find this.*

> The maximum number of concurrent builds that Jenkins may perform on this agent.
>   A good value to start with would be the number of CPU cores on the machine. Setting a higher value would cause each build to take longer, but could increase the overall throughput. For example, one build might be CPU-bound, while a second build running at the same time might be I/O-bound — so the second build could take advantage of the spare I/O capacity at that moment.
>
> Agents must have at least one executor. To temporarily prevent any builds from being executed on an agent, use the Mark this node temporarily offline button on the agent's page.
>
> This does not apply to the Jenkins master — setting the number of executors to zero will prevent any builds from being executed on the master.

From what I can grok, it depends on what exactly your jobs are doing; our deployment scripts simply execute `gcloud` commands and so we run those on an instance with a higher number of executors. Our selenium tests, however, run on an instance with 1 executor/core. From what it seems though, we're playing it a bit on the safe side.

Comment: It would be nice to know the source of your quotation and what "our" means in your answer (used twice).

Comment: @sebadagostino Good call :) - I've updated where to find the thing. As for "our", I mean at the company I work for.